# Prove $\det(1+tA)=1+t\cdot tr(A)+O(t^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, trace

I need help proving

$\det(1+tA)=1+t\cdot \operatorname{tr}(A)+O(t^2)$

I'm not really sure where to start due to the $(1+tA)$, the $1$ is throwing me off.

Comment: Do you know that the determinant of a $n\times n$ matrix can be written as a sum of $n!$ monomials in the matrix entries?  In your problem, one of these monomials is your friend, the others are $O(t^2)$.

Comment: the expression on the right its just some part of the product of the diagonal of $1+tA$, and all the other part of this product and other products of the determinant are included in the $O(t^2)$. Because the $1$ (together with the $t$) you knows that the diagonal of $1+tA$ have no zeros, hence the estimate on the right.

Comment: @kimchilover: Don't waste your friends ;) There is a total of $n+1$ "friendly" monomials, not just one.

Comment: You are right and I am wrong, with regard to monomials in the entries of $A$.  I was trying to say the monomials  in the entries of the matrix $M=I+tA$, one should focus on $\prod M_{ii} $ which of course evaluates to $ \prod (1+tA_{ii})$, and so on etc. ( In fact I count ALL monomials as my friends, and we have pizza parties regularly.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the most common definition of the determinant is a sum of products of matrix elements, for the computation the definition as $(Tv_1)\wedge\dotsb\wedge(Tv_n)=\det(T)v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_n$ is the most useful.

Putting $T=1+tA$, we use the distributive law and gather like terms to get

$$
(1+tA)v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge(1+tA)v_n = v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_n\\+t(Av_1\wedge v_2\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_n + v_1\wedge Av_2\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_n +\dotsb+v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge Av_n)+\\ \dotsb + t^n(Av_1\wedge Av_2\wedge\dotsb\wedge Av_n).
$$

If the $v_i$ are a basis, then we have $Av_i=A_i^jv_j,$ and so $$v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge Av_i\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_n=A_i^i(v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_i\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_n),$$

so our sum becomes

$$
(1+tA)v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge(1+tA)v_n = v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_n\\+t(\text{tr}(A))+ \dotsb + t^n(Av_1\wedge Av_2\wedge\dotsb\wedge Av_n)\\=(1+\text{tr}(A)t+O(t^2))v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_n.
$$

Thus $\det(1+tA)=1+\text{tr}(A)t+O(t^2)$ as was to be proved.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $A$ is $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C}).$ Suppose that $A$ is diagonalizable, with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n.$ Then $1+tA$ is also diagonalizable, with eigenvalues $1+t\lambda_i.$ The determinant of a diagonalizable matrix is the product of its eigenvalues, so we have

$$
\det(1+tA)=(1+t\lambda_1)\cdot\dotsb\cdot(1+t\lambda_n)\\=1+t(\lambda_1+\dotsb+\lambda_n)+\dotsb + t^n(\lambda_1\cdot\dotsb\cdot\lambda_n)\\=1+\text{tr}(A)t+\dotsb+t^n\det(A)=1+\text{tr}(A)t + O(t^2).
$$

If $A$ is not diagonalizable, observe that the diagonalizable matrices are dense in $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C}).$ By continuity, the above equation also holds for $A$.

Comment: Why two separate answers? I suggest to include both approaches in a single thread.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I was under the impression that the site practice was to prefer not to have multiple disparate questions submitted as one, nor multiple answers submitted. For the sake of containment and segregation of voting, discussion, readability, etc. I thought I had even read suggestions to that effect in an FAQ, but a little searching turns up no such guidance, so maybe I'm misremembering. Do you think I should merge the two answers?